# Setup and style qTips jquery

Tags: jquery, tooltip, qtip

No matter what I do I cant seem to get my tool tips to look how they are on the website:

http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#tips

I want my tooltip to look like the above, when: -

- Need to onclick or hover on an 16px by 16px information icon, then display the tooltip.
- Needs to have a nice fade effect.
- Needs to target the title attribute with a class. So if the link has a class of myToolTip the tooltip is displayed.

Can anyone help me, driving me daft!

Cheers

Comment: Did you notice the thick blue banner at the top of the [qTip page](http://craigsworks.com/projects/qtip/features/#tips)?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#toolTipElementId').qtip({
        content: 'Tooltip Text to be displayed ',
        style: { 
            tip: 'topLeft',
            border: {
                width: 2,
                radius: 5,
                color: '#6699CC'
            },
            width: 200
        }  
    });
});
```